# Telerik RadGrid (ASP .Net) - Page Size filter Bug / Lost

Tags: filter, pagination, telerik, radgrid

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgRecentSubmissions" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    PageSize="10" GridLines="None" Skin="Office2007">
```

By default, the RadGrid displays 10 records and has a drop-down filter to increase the page size to 20 or 50 records. Upon selecting another value in the drop-down, the page reloads (postback) and the RadGrid is extended to display more records as selected.

Now, an issue arises when you have less than 50 records and you select the value 50 for page size. After post-back, the drop-down filter is lost and you can't reselect to a lower page size value.

Anyone experience this or might know why this is so? I just need to retain the drop-down selector regardless of page size and number of records.

**UPDATE**
Ok, I tried to post some images but can't since I allegedly don't have enough "reputation points"

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this declaration:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgRecentSubmissions" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    PageSize="10" GridLines="None" Skin="Office2007" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true">
```

What I did here was take the PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible property and set it to true, worked like a charm :) You could of course open up `<PagerStyle></PagerStyle>` tags in your RadGrid markup if you feel like that is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm indeed :)